How can I add an image to the top of the TOC in a quarto HTML Document
How can I add an image above the table of contents (TOC) in a Quarto html document?
I'm able to add an image to the top of the table of contents (TOC) in a Rmarkdown report using the following code:

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#TOC').parent().prepend('<div id=\"nav_logo\"><img src=\"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7a/Posit_logo.svg/640px-Posit_logo.svg.png\"></div>');
  });
</script>

<style>
#TOC { 
margin-top: 120px; <!-- toc top from page top -->
} 
#nav_logo {
  position: fixed; 
  width: 240px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>

which produces this:
Rmarkdown Example
But I am unable to replicate this in Quarto.

Maybe start with providing a minimal, reproducible example showing your attempts in quarto.


luckily Quarto is based a lot around Rmarkdown. you can use the same solution provided here. Atleast don't have to specify the navbar, and may have to play around with the background-size paramter and different TOC and image layouts.
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
toc: true
toc-depth: 2
---
<style>
#TOC {
  background: url("logo.png");
  background-size: 50%;
  padding-top: 80px !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
## Quarto
## Running Code

